# Yarn pnp causes drive letter mismatch on Windows with Testcafe

Tags: typescript, testing, testcafe, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

Testcafe is unable to compile my test with yarn pnp, I run into the following error after switching to yarn pnp by setting these two properties inside of .yarnrc:

```
nodeLinker: "pnp"
pnpMode: "strict"
```

The error message:

```
code: 'E1035'
Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
C:/testcafe/test.ts (13, 17): File name 
'C:/testcafe/.yarn/cache/testcafe-npm-2.0.0-395078fea1-9192f88fb7.zip/node_modules/testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts' 
differs from already included file name 
'c:/testcafe/.yarn/cache/testcafe-npm-2.0.0-395078fea1-9192f88fb7.zip/node_modules/testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts' only in casing.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
    Imported via 'testcafe' from file 'C:/testcafe/test.ts' with packageId 'testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts@2.0.0'
```

`forceConsistentCasingInFileNames: false` does not function as a workaround as it is not the file but path name

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue is related to "yarn" and has already been fixed (see https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/7007). Make sure you are using the `yarn` version with the necessary fix.

Comment: I am using the latest yarn version, my guess is that the issue is, while yarn uses lower case only, testcafe might import itself internally during compillation with a uppercase drive letter

Comment: It is not clear from your description how you encountered this error. Please share with us the steps required to reproduce it.

Comment: I have set the nodeLinker and pnpmode property inside the .yarnrc file to activate pnp, then i tried to run a test, the error occurs during testcafe runtime but before tests are executed

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem by using the steps you described, but didn't manage to.
Please add changes to the https://github.com/felis2803/testcafe-temp-5 repository so that the bug can be reproduced, or create your own repository that we can run and explore.